# How do I convert a minute number to human-readable format in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Is there a way to format the following number (in minutes) to human readable text:

```
60 > 01:00:00
60.5 > 01:00:30
24 > 00:24:00
1.5 > 00:01:30
80 > 01:20:00
120 > 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your posted raw data were in A2:A. In B2 of an otherwise empty range B2:B, place the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A/24/60))`

Then select Col B entirely and apply the following format:

**Format > Number > Custom number format >** *hh:mm:ss*

`/24/60` divides your raw numbers by 24 hours per day and then 60 minutes per hour. You could just use `A2:A/1440`, but I find that seeing `/24/60` makes more sense to most people.